# How do you make 'Rabri'?

Tags: milk, dessert, indian-cuisine, pudding

It's an Indian, or to be more specific, Bengali pudding. Its milky with sheets/pieces of something akin to 'hard milk'. I've never seen a recipe for it and the Wikipedia article is vague indeed.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYTT-ZgJQok&feature=related

Comment: Many thanks, I know what I'm doing at the weekend now!

PS. You should post your response as an answer rather than a comment so I can give you points ;-)

Comment: @Orbling - sadly its not quite what I would call Rabri - in Bengal (where the finest Indian sweets are made ;-) ) its made without nuts and loads of spices etc. and makes for a simple and very elegant dessert. This version is not quite it, but if nothing its given me more of an idea of what is involved. Thanks again for posting.

I'll keep looking ...

Comment: Rabri/Rabdi is a huge class of dish, individual variations on the theme must number in the millions.  The main benefit of watching the video I figured, was that you would get the idea of the reduction process involved, the additions are up to you. :-)

Comment: As for making it an answer, well - it did not seem sufficient for an answer, just a shove in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

There's a recipe at [Indian Food Forever](http://www.indianfoodforever.com/desserts/rabri.html), although I've never made it, tried it, or even heard of it before, so I cannot attest to the validity of the recipe. A quick [Google search for "rabri"](http://www.google.com/search?q=rabri) will turn up a few more links to recipes in the first page of results.

Comment: Google search! Of course! (Puts palm to forehead) Now why didn't I think of that ...?

Comment: @5arx: You *did* say in your question, *"I've never seen a recipe for it."* This actually demonstrates handily why we've never permitted recipe requests here; the more your question looks like one, the more probable this type of answer becomes. Perhaps the question would have been better worded as *"What do I need to do to make Rabri more like [copy-and-paste description from your second comment] and less like [results from recipe that didn't work out so well]?"*

Comment: Interesting... never read the FAQ for this site. (Never posted on this site before today, either). Glad I haven't asked for any recipes! Fortunately, I know how to use Google for that (i.e. see answer above :P )

Answer (score -1):

http://www.indianfoodforever.com/desserts/rabri.html is a link to a recipe for Rabri I hope this is a help

Comment: This is the exact same recipe link that was posted the first time.